# get subset of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get a subset of a table, here's the example:

```
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   B
5   C
6   D
7   D
8   D
```

I want to get the unique record, but with the smallest id:

```
1   A
3   B
5   C
6   D
```

How can I write the SQL in SQL Server? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select min(id), othercol
from thetable
group by othercol
```

and maybe with

```
order by othercol
```

... at the end if thats important

Answer (score 4):

Use a common-table expression like this:

```
;WITH DataCTE AS
(
   SELECT ID, OtherCol,
      ROW_NUM() OVER(PARTITION BY OtherCol ORDER BY ID) 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM DataCTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This "partitions" your data by the second column you have (`A, B, C`) and orders by the `ID` (`1, 2, 3`) - smallest ID first.

Therefore, for each "partition" (i.e. each value of your second column), the entry with `RowNum = 1` is the one with the smallest ID for each value of the second column.

Comment: +1                                              @JohnnySun: It might look complicated but analytic queries are easy once you understand the basic structure of the query and also they are the ones what you need if you want to pick more than one column that cannot be in a group by clause

Comment: @JohnnySun: but this is very powerful - you can get the top three entries for each value, for instance (`WHERE RowNum <= 3`) - none of the other approaches can do something like that!

Comment: +1 : Not only is this more flexible and powerful, this can also often out-perform the aggregation approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, Name
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select min(id), column2
from table
group by column2
```

It helps if you provide the table information in the question - I've just guessed at the column names...